# How to fix the two button center and right side? im expecting the best answer without using "dp".please guide me

Tags: android, layout

I'm creating a login form and i would like to set the back Button as center and reg Button at the right side.

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="onBackClick"
        android:background="@color/l_green"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reg"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:minWidth="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="onSigninClick"
        android:background="@color/l_blue"/>
```

Comment: Which type of layout are you using Linear or Relative?

Comment: You need to clarify your question, possibly with some sort of mockup or diagram. Also, I don't see anything in that layout that would be considered a "red button".

Comment: its linear layout and orientation in horizontal

Comment: provide the full code for better understanding of your question & best answer to b provided.

Comment: Create an image of the result you want, upload to an image hosting service, and add a link to it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I usually do:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="onBackClick"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dummy"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:text="login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:minWidth="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dummy"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:onClick="onSigninClick"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In practice:

- I set a dummy View to the center of the screen
- I set a Button to the left of it
- I set the other one to the right of it

Comment: you tried to teach me... but now i realized your answer is exactly right. Thanks and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

you could use weight, it would evenly distribute, regardless of screen size

would be like:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:weightSum=3
     android:layout_width=fill_parent>
     <View    // filler
          android:weight=1>
     </View>
     <Button   // back button
          android:weight=1>
     </Button>
     <Button   // cancel button
          android:weight=1>
     </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try this according to your question

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="onBackClick"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:text="login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:minWidth="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:onClick="onSigninClick"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot of the emulated app with two buttons]

Comment: but still the two buttons are in left side only... used layout_center but it doesn't show any changes

Comment: try that code . i am attached screen shot . watch that.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
   <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/back"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:onClick="onBackClick"
    android:weight="1"
    android:background="@color/l_green"/>
  <View
    android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/reg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:minWidth="130dp"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:weight="1"
    android:onClick="onSigninClick"
    android:background="@color/l_blue"/>
</LinearLayout>
```